# Buoyancy Correction for a Kater Pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics

`Question`:

> Consider a Kater pendulum: that is, a rod with two cylindrical masses at both ends, with a knife edge between the two masses and another between one of the masses and the end of the rod. Write the corrected expression for the period $T_0$ as $T_0=T(1\pm T_B)$, where $T$ is the uncorrected period $2\pi/\omega$ and $T_B$ is the correction term for the buoyancy of the pendulum in air.

`Attempt`: Let $\rho$ be the density of the air, $V$ the volume of the pendulum, and $g$ the acceleration due to gravity. I make the postulate that the buoyant force $F_b=\rho V g$ is acting on the center of mass. Therefore, $\vec{\tau}_{net}=\vec{r}_{cm}\times \vec{F_{net}}$, where $\vec{F}_{net}$ is the net force and $\vec{\tau}_{net}$ is the net torque. Simplifying, we have

$$\vec{F}_{net}=-mg\hat{z}+\rho g V \hat{z}$$
$$\rightarrow \vec{\tau}_{net}=-mg\hat{r}_{cm}\times \hat{z}+\rho g V \hat{r}_{cm}\times \hat{z}$$

here, $I$ is the moment of inertia of the pendulum and $\theta$ is the angular displacement.

$$\mid \vec{\tau}_{net}\mid=-(m-\rho V)g\hat{r}_{cm}\sin\theta=I\ddot{\theta}$$
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{(m-\rho V)g r_{cm}}{I}\theta=0$$

$$T=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{I}{(m-\rho V)gr_{cm}}}$$

Simplifying again, we have

$$T_0=T\sqrt{1-\frac{\rho V}{m}}$$
Performing a Taylor expansion, we now have

$$T_0\approx T(1-\frac{\rho V}{2m})$$

$$\rightarrow T_B=\frac{\rho V}{2m}$$
My question is this: is it correct to assume that the net buoyant force acts at the center of mass of the Kater pendulum system? If not, how would I go about finding the resultant buoyant correction? I have no idea how to go about it unless making the above postulate. Thank you in advance.